# Minimum battery consumption for microphone threshold monitoring in Android

Tags: android, performance, audio, microphone

I would like to design a small Android app which triggers an event when the microphone's threshold is above a specific raw value.

Something along the lines of this: http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/wiki/NoiseAlert

As it is an always-on service, I'd like to keep battery consumption to minimum.

I understand that sound amplitude is not something that is handled by the system (am I right?), so I must calculate it from the raw values. In addition, I cannot measure amplitude without recording...

So that leaves me with taking care that there will be minimum effort for the CPU. I can use lowest 8kHz sample, but even that is overkill just for calculating aplitude.

Is there a way to use an ultra low sampling rate, like 50Hz or even 20Hz?

And in general, what advice is there to help me maintain bat consumption to a minimum using that application...?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "always-on service" + audio recording is not a particularly good combination on Android. Many (most?) Android devices out there only allow one audio recording instance at any given time, so your service would effectively break all other apps that want to record audio. I haven't looked at KitKat to see if this has been fixed, but I remember that it wtill was a problem on Jellybean.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to suck the battery dry really quickly.   And a phone with a flat battery is a terrible user-experience.

I doubt the sample-rate will have a huge effect on power consumption.  However, buffer period will.

Whilst the phone will need to keep the audio codec, DMA engines and memory controller active pretty much the whole time, you can at least limit the number of times the CPU is woken up (a power hungry operation).  In addition, processing a large number of samples at one is considerably cheaper per-sample that processing a small number infrequently.

Whether AudioFlinger modifies its own buffer period in response to active applications, I don't know.  You might have to go direct with ALSA (on phones that have it).  This has the added benefit of reducing the amount of code executed for each buffer period.

Comment: I'll just add that some mobile platforms (Qualcomm's MSM8974 comes to mind) has support for always-on voice detection/recognition at the platform level, which supposedly is power-efficient and doesn't interfere with apps that want to record audio. But as long as this type of functionality is non-standard I suspect that it'll be available only to OEMs.